# Reference for discrete interpolation inequalities.

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

I am trying to extend some results in continuous cases to discrete cases. May I ask if there is any reference for discrete Sobolev's inequality and discrete Agmon's inequality? Thanks!

Comment: You should be more specific. What inequality do you want to prove? What means `discrete case'?

Comment: For example, if I have a square mesh grid and using the finite difference method to discretize the problem, is there any reference that has proved that the maximum norm is bounded by the product of discrete H1 norm and discrete H2 norm, which is induced by standard 5-point Laplacian in 2D case? In the continuous case,  this is guaranteed by Agmon's inequality.